# How to compare more three arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to compare a lot of arrays.
I have an array of objects like it :

```
cart = [0]{products:[ id : 10, name: 'bla' ], ingredient: [id: 20, name: 'bla' count : 0]}
       [1]{products:[ id : 10, name: 'bla' ], ingredient: [id: 20, name: 'bla' count : 0]}
```

I want to compare the `ingredients array` and if it's the same object or objects in the arrays I want to delete the full line of the `cart array` and add 1 to the `count`.

I see solution on web but they just compare with the previous index. If I have 3 object I want compare the first and the third too.

How I can do that please?

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(cart) {
  const existingIngredients = [];
  return cart.filter(row => {
    // using lodash isEqual in the next line, but you can write your own comparison function
    if(existingIngredients.some(existing => _.isEqual(row.ingredients, existing))) {
      count++;
      return false; // filter out this row
    } else {
      existingIngredients.push(row.ingredients);
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```

I'm using a very crude approach here with storing existing ingredients in an array, but you get the idea.